# Python dataframe column drop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a row that has Recommended in the Status column, I want to then delete all job ID's with that matching ID regardless of Status. For example, if Job ID 1234 has any employee with status Recommended, then remove it from the dataframe. I would like a way to do this without having to manually input the job ID in each line to be dropped from the dataframe. The way I am currently doing it is manually inputting the job ID to the following Python code:

x.drop(x[x['Job ID'] == '1234'].index, inplace = True)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jq97V.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'job_id': 1, 'status': 'Recommended'},
        {'job_id': 1, 'status': 'Not Recommended'},
        {'job_id': 2, 'status': 'Never Recommended'},
        {'job_id': 2, 'status': 'Not Recommended'},
        {'job_id': 3, 'status': 'Never Recommended'},
        {'job_id': 3, 'status': 'R U kidding?'},
        {'job_id': 3, 'status': 'No, for real...'},
        {'job_id': 4, 'status': 'Recommended'},
        {'job_id': 4, 'status': 'Not Recommended'}]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)

#Show the dataframe
print(df.to_string())

#Get the job_id of any row with a status of Recommended; there might be duplicates, so do a unique
ids_to_delete = df[df["status"] == "Recommended"]["job_id"].unique()

#Use the ~ operator to get the records that don't have an ID in the list generated in the prior step
df = df[~df["job_id"].isin(ids_to_delete)]

#Show the dataframe; any row that had a status of Recommended is now gone
print(df.to_string())
```